# mySQL: Replacing all instances of /n with <p>

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to run a query that will replace all instances of `'/n'` (which appears to be a hidden field) with `<p>`.

I have the following SQL

```
UPDATE dbname.products  SET text_column = REPLACE (text_column, '\r\n', '<p>');
```

I get the error Unknown column 'text' in 'field list'

Can anyone see an issue here?

Thanks

Comment: Best not to place html markup into your data. Better to parse the data at the time of display. Maybe using <blockquote></blockquote> is an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's a work around for tiny mce

Comment: I get an error 'Unknown column 'text' in field list'

Comment: Firstly, can you let us know what errors are coming up.  Secondly, you won't get a `<p>` when the new lines are simply \n. Also, there will be no closing of the `<p>` tags in the markup for you, and you'll also get `<p><p>` if someone has entered a double line break.

Comment: Just going by your error, does products have a column named "text_column" or "text"?

Comment: It does yes, very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be the space after `replace()`.  MySQL is finicky about spaces after function names, as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html).

So, try:

```
UPDATE dbname.products
  SET text_column = REPLACE(text_column, '\r\n', '<p>');
```